# SSH_INTERPRETER for VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm

Is there such thing as the *PyCharm* `SSH_Interpreter` option for *Visual Studio Code*?

For remote debugging I am finding the option to install and modify files with `ptvsd` ([here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_remote-debugging)).

However, is there a way to go straight through `ssh` instead of having to jump all those `ptvsd` hoops?
I am not a big fan of having to add `ptvsc` hooks into every file I want to debug.

Comment: I believe support for the scenarios you're thinking of is coming to the experimental debugger.

Comment: @BrettCannon Thanks. Do you have a link to that?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/538

Comment: @BrettCannon Thanks! I'm wondering, why do you need to have `ptvsd` installed the remote side? Would it not be straight forward to use the `ssh` tunnel as `PyCharm` does it?

Comment: You need the debugger on the remote side to do the actual debugging work. Are you asking if we could just send the file over automatically?

Comment: I am looking at how `PyCharm` does it and to me it seems you do not have to inject code into the remote file to be able to debug code. They seem to run `ssh` only. However, this might not work for VS Code because it supports a plethora of languages, I get that. But the `PyCharm` ssh tunneling for `Python` is really nice compared to code injection.